# How to tell C# RichTextBox to select lines via keyboard like other apps

Tags: c#, richtextbox, selection

I am using .NET 4.0 but this also occurs in 2.0...

In my opinion, a RichTextBox in MultiLine mode should not select lines of text the way it does.

In the control, input several lines of text with at least one empty line in the middle, like this:

> The quick brown fox jumps
> over lazy dog.
>
> More people prefer
> apples to oranges.

It should be possible to place the insertion point at the beginning (before "The") and use the keyboard's Down arrow key to select the first two lines--*not* including the blank line below it, yet it includes the blank line.  I know it's not a big thing to hit the Left arrow key to deselect the blank line but it *is* annoying and besides, it should work like other applications and like the TextBox control.

I looked at the control's properties and found nothing but perhaps there is one and I can't think of what it is named.

Must I write this behaviour myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool HasIgnoredSelection { get; set; }

HasIgnoredSelection = false;

rtb.KeyUp += (e) => {
     int cursorIndex = rtb.SelectionStart + rtb.SelectionLength;
     bool isBlankLineSelection = e.Shift 
         && e.KeyCode == Keys.Down 
         && rtb.Lines[rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(cursorIndex)] == Environment.NewLine;

     if (!HasIgnoredSelection 
         && isBlankLineSelection) 
     {
        rtb.SelectionLength -= Environment.NewLine.Length;
        HasIgnoredSelection = true;
     }
     else if (isBlankLineSelection)
     {
        HasIgnoredSelection = false;
        rtb.SelectionLength += Environment.NewLine.Length;
     }
     else 
     {
        HasIgnoredSelection = false;
     }
};
```

Of course, this is the hacky way of doing it that you were talking about, though I'm not sure this is even what you want. It would prevent you from continuing to select text by the keyboard unless you held the Down key, so there's other ways you could approach this.

edit: added the ability to press down twice to get it to jump to the line after the blank line

Comment: Thanks for the response but even when I try to tweak it (for instance, change Environment.NewLine to "" and add/subtract just one to/from the length) it still does not behave like a normal textbox should.  

I should have mentioned that highlighting several lines and copy/pasting them also does not paste as it should.  Strange, I don't think the unmanaged RichEdit control has these problems.